# Sitecore Speak UI what layout and renderings for dialog opened from launchpad, desktop or content editor

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-speak-ui

What layout and renderings should be used to create a dialog/app which can be started from

1. Launchpad
2. Content Editor button
3. Desktop start menu shortcut

As an example; here are images of the User Manager dialog. Note the differences in the appearance of the header bar in each case. I tried to examine this control in Sitecore to see how it was developed, but it is implemented in Sheer UI, not SPEAK UI. Can this be done automatically with a particular layout and combination of renderings, or would I need to detect the context of the application to control whether the launchpad icon is displayed in the top left corner of the dialog?

**User Manager - launched from Launchpad**
[image: User Manager - launched from Launchpad]

**User Manager - launched from Content Editor**
[image: User Manager - launched from Content Editor]

**User Manager - launched from Desktop Start Menu**
[image: User Manager - launched from Desktop Start Menu]

Comment: HI Matt, i can tell you that the user manager example here is actually Sheer UI rather than SPEAK. For a dialog to get the header etc, there is a dialog rendering you can add. I'm not sure on the launch button but ill see i can find out.

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you that the user manager example here is actually Sheer UI rather than SPEAK.

For the dialog header use the "DialogPageStucture", "DashboardPageStrucuture" will give you the "GlobalHeader" placeholder as used below. I'm not sure how you mix and match them as the User Manager is Sheer UI rather than SPEAK.

For the launch pad button and header use "GlobalHeader" and "GlobalLogo" (this is the launch pad button). Add GlobalHeader into the GlobalHeader placeholder. Add GlobalLogo into GlobalHeader.StartButton.

Comment: Cool thanks for the info. I was already using the "Task" PageStructure rendering and tried the "Dialog" one as well, but obviously to switch between the two (maybe using some rules?) would require duplicating  child renderings into each different PageStructure rendering. Interestingly I have a Sheer UI app which I launch from the desktop and the launchpad and that gets handled the same way as the User Manager.